# Monopoly Deal - Rent beyond a complete set

Tags: monopoly-deal

In monopoly deal it is possible, due to wild cards, to have more than a complete property set for a single color.

Given that fact, and the text of a rent card:

> Choose one of these colors. All players pay you rent for all Properties you own in that color.

Are other players required to pay you for the sum total of all property sets of that color, or simply the rent from only your largest property set of that color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me preface with the warning that Monopoly deal is not a game with a rigorous rules set, so we need to infer from what we have.

The rules state:

> Each card shows how many properties there are to collect in that color-set.

The rules also refer to a complete set as a "full set"

Finally, each card only itemizes the rent paid for numbers of properties up to the full size of the set.

From this, we can conclude that you cannot use wilds to charge extra rent by "overcompleting" a set because there is no defined rent for doing so.

I would further argue that the terminology "full set" implies that you cannot "overcomplete" a set for any reason (such as to make them immune to Sly Deal).